# Creating a horizontal list of images objects and links

Tags: html, css, menu

So to start this off I would like to just say that any help is appreciated, I'm not looking for the entire code laid out for me. I have tried to create this but fail every time as something disappears of it breaks the entire layout of the page. I am fairly new to programming but I have a pretty good grasp of concepts and I'm open to learning new things.

I would like to create a top bar like in this website, with the logo and social icons. No search bar.
http://www.complex.com/

Thank you to anyone for any help

Comment: I've tried putting everything into an unordered list and then inline the elements but that breaks the layout of everything.

Comment: That could also be because of how you are setting the `position` of each element.

Comment: I didn't set any position. I never used positioning before with css strangely so I'm reading up on it now.

Comment: Right, I guess what I meant to say is how you are or are not setting the positioning of each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply either CSS `float: left` or `display: inline-block` to your elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/njoh7x73/

**CSS code**

```
.menu {
    background-color: #333;
}

.menu div.item {
    width: 64px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #888;
}

.menu .item {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.menu .item:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="item" href="#">LINK</a>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <a class="item" href="#">LINK</a>
    <div class="item"></div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div
```

If you use this approach (floating elements), don't forget to `clear` them.

Answer (score 1):

First, as a general tip: Whenever you see something you want to recreate, right click on it in chrome and select "inspect element". Then you can look at the css used to create it.

To have social icons up like your example site, they've simple floated them right.

So HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="leftThing">
  </div>
  <div class="rightThing">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftThing { float:left;}
.rightThing { float:right;}
```

The float will cause the element to go as far to the side you select as it can, then sit there. Here is a good css tricks article on the concept: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

I made you a litte JS-Fiddle to show you how to fix the header on top of the screen when you scroll down. Hope it helps a bit!

HTML:

```
<div id="WebContent" class="Content">
    <img src='http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/9712/orionfull_jcc_big.jpg'></img>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Header{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    min-width: 1024px;
    background-color: #2C2C2C;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
}

.icon{
    height: 50px;
}

.Content{
    max-width: 300;
    max-height: 300;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wujood/pgqeLr7s/

Or you can just insert a fixed position to your header:

```
<div class="header" style="position:fixed">
  <div class="leftThing">
  </div>
  <div class="rightThing">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like that and it works in the link you gave me but i just tried implementing it on my site and the header is white it won't change colors, do you know why?

Comment: Scratch that, I didn't capitalize what you had capitalized.

Comment: I added something more basic without the css. Changed it in this post. Please tell me if it helps!